# How do I INSERT into a database with a primary autoincrement key?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, auto-increment

So I have a table that is laid out according to:

```
CREATE TABLE `dealerships` (
  `dealership_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `zone` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fax` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL',
  `servicephone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dealership_id`)
)
COMMENT='This stores dealership information. '
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now when I insert with

`INSERT INTO dealerships (dealership_id, ~the rest~), VALUES( NULL, ~values);`

This returns an error that `dealership_id` cannot be `NULL` error 1048.

`INSERT INTO dealerships (dealership_id, ~the rest~), VALUES(0, ~values);`

This returns an error that `dealership_id` already exists for value `0`.

`INSERT INTO dealerships (dealership_id, ~the rest~), VALUES(default, ~values);`

This returns an error that `dealership_id` has no default value error 1364.

When I simply say screw it, and ommit dealership_id

`INSERT INTO dealerships (~the rest~), VALUES(~values);`

I get the error that a value must be specified for `dealership_id`.

Every-time I've worked with `autoincrement primary keys`. Normally inserting `NULL` would work for the index to do the auto-magical things for me. What is happening??

Platform Specific Information:

MariaDB10.1.18 x64

Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: You have to define a column as auto-incrementing. For the first column, after the `NOT NULL` you need ` AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

For create add AUTO_INCREMENT

```
CREATE TABLE `dealerships` (
  `dealership_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zone` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fax` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL',
  `servicephone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dealership_id`)
)
COMMENT='This stores dealership information. '
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and for insert don't insert the key  (is automatically create by auto increment)

```
insert into  `dealerships`  (

  `zone`,
  `phone`,
  `fax` ,
  `name`,
  `address1`,
  `address2`',
  `servicephone` ,
  `timezone`

  )  values (
      'vale_zone',
      1,
      2 ,
      'val_name',
      'val_address1',
      'val_address2',
      3 ,
    'val_timezone'
  )
```

Comment: See my OP. When I omit the key I receive error 1364 that `dealership_id` doesn't have a default value.

Comment: But have you also set the column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: why downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

To insert a field with auto increment property, use *ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT* in the create table.

```
CREATE TABLE `dealerships` (
  `dealership_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zone` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `fax` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` CHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL',
  `servicephone` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` CHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dealership_id`)
)
COMMENT='This stores dealership information. '
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After, you have two solutions to insert data.

### Solution 1

```
INSERT INTO dealerships(zone, phone, fax, name) VALUES('zone1', '00000', '00000', 'name1')
```

In this case I chossen to add data in only few columns (add the others on the wame way).

### Solution 2

```
INSERT INTO dealerships SET zone = 'zone1', phone = '0000', name = 'Eddy'
```

Here, I used the field `SET field = value, field2 = value2`.

> As you can see I didn't added any reference to the ID. Normal, the field is AUTO_INCREMENT mode, and Mysql (or tothers SGBD) will create automatically a value.

Of course, you can force the value:

```
INSERT INTO dealerships SET dealership_id = 10, zone = 'zone1', phone = '0000', name = 'Eddy'

INSERT INTO dealerships(dealership_id, zone, phone, fax, name) VALUES(9, 'zone1', '00000', '00000', 'name1')
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

### About your errors

1. Normal. You specified `NOT NULL`
2. Normal, there is already a record for the value 0 (check your database)
3. Normal. You can't use `default`. This is a constant with his own value (1364).
4. Normal, the field as if can't be ommited
   The only way to does not have this issue is to remove completely the reference of the ID field. Use the solution described :)

Answer (score 0):

Georges explained it all for you. If you want to add auto increment to table just run this sql statement

`ALTER TABLE dealerships MODIFY COLUMN  dealership_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

This will add the auto increment property on the column dealership_id. And if you want to change auto increment start value run this (Change 100 to your start value)

`ALTER TABLE dealerships AUTO_INCREMENT=100;`